# telerik maskedtextbox with a RegularExpressionValidator

Tags: c#, asp.net, regex, telerik, maskedtextbox

Just wondering if anyone had this issue before:

I'm using a Telerik maskedtextbox.  Let say the mask is '#####'.
I can enter 1-5 digits and all is good.
If I add a RegularExpressionValidator to the field, it will always fail unless I enter exactly the amount of digits specified in the mask.

ex.
just the maskedtextbox with mask '#####', I can enter 1, 11, 111, 1111, 11111 and all is good.
If I add a RegularExpressionValidator, it fails unless the input is 11111.

The regex expression is fine until it's used with the masked control

Comment: What's your regex ?

Comment: use any regex u want that'll accept any number of digits from 1-5.  you'll see your regex is good until the regex validator is tied to the masked control.  then you have to match whats in the mask

ex. ^\d{0,5}$       1-5 digits but if my mask is 5, then I have to enter all 5